# Sending Java HTTP request results in login failed, but succeeds when using webbrowser

Tags: java, http

I want to control a device, whose functionalities are only accessible through a web interface. So I want to build a kind of wrapper for the device's functionalities.

The web interface requires you to login first, and then you have some buttons within the interface.

So I tried to send (using Java) an HTTP POST request with the login parameters to the server. The webserver *does* return a 200 OK, but the problem is, the returning HTML document states that it "Failed to login".

Strangely, when I use my webbrowser and try to log in using web interface's login form, then the login succeeds.

I used the Live HTTP Headers Firefox addon, and some of the headers sent by my browser, I copied an applied within my Java code snippet. At least the `Accept`, `Content-Length` and `Content-Type` headers and the contents where similar.

I'm using the following code:

```
String query = "somekey=somevalue&anotherkey=anothervalue";

URL url = new URL("http://" + this.address + "/somesubdir");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.addRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
conn.addRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + query.length());
conn.getOutputStream().write(query.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

What is the cause of the problem? Does it have something to do with sessions or something?

Comment: Can you add more details? Are you using the same URL and POST body that the browser when trying to login?

Comment: Did you check the login protocol thoroughly? It may require a cookie to already exist when you are sending the POST. Or there might be a challenge-response field that needs to be integrated into the POST.

Comment: I added some more details. I do not know whether a cookie already exist or something.

Comment: I could almost bet that if it's neither of the options that RealSkeptic mentioned, you have run into a nonce, which is a mechanism to prevent against cross site request forgery. Read up on what that is and how it works, so you can build a request to actually login.

Comment: Did you try setting the user-agent http header? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent

Comment: I don't fully understand how the device can tell the difference between a normal webbrowser and my piece of Java code.

Comment: Are you sure that your query string is correct? Maybe you need to use the [URLEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) class to correctly encode the values.